# How to clone/copy a sql record with CakePhp?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, clone, record

How to clone/copy a sql record with CakePhp? 
Is there a native way or do I need to *find* my record and then *save* it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no native "copy" command by itself. But a find/read operation followed by a create/save should work.

```
$row = $this->Model->findById(1);
$this->Model->create(); // Create a new record
$this->Model->save($row); // And save it
```

Would copy the row with id 1.

Comment: Unsetting the `$row['Model']['id']` would be useful, otherwise the same record is going to be overwritten by itself and the end result is that nothing changed.

Answer (score 18):

You need to use the find and save function.

```
$record = $this->Model->findById(1);
$record['Model']['id'] = NULL;
$this->Model->save($record);
```